# Getting error building CraftAR-Phonegap plugin sample application

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm running Cordova 4.3, and the latest version of the craftAR plugin for Phonegap (https://github.com/Catchoom/craftar-phonegap). I'm trying to run the sample application which is included with the plugin.

Once the sample application builds and launches(from the Cordova CLI tools, not Android Studio), it dies with a "Unfortunately HelloCordova has stopped". This is the error I'm getting from the log after

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, any help in solving this would be appreciated. I'm just a lowly web developer, and errors from real languages scare me!!

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but are you sure your plugin ref is in config.xml?

Comment: Thanks Steve, not a dumb question. It was present in the config.xml in the /platforms/android/res/xml directory, but not in the config.xml in the root directory. I added it there, but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately. That does seem to likely be the culprit, though, as the error implies that the plugin has a null reference. Anywhere else I should look to add the reference?

Comment: Steve: Thanks for your help, I ended up checking the plugin docs, and I guess I need to downgrade my Cordova version AGAIN!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to downgrade your Cordova version.

Comment: Yep, the plugin requires =< 3.0.